# Program crashes when using SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface()

Tags: c++, sdl-2, sdl-ttf

```
SDL_Texture *Graphics::createTexture(TTF_Font *font, const char *text, SDL_Color color, int wrap) {
    SDL_Surface *surface = TTF_RenderText_Blended_Wrapped(font, text, color, wrap);
    SDL_Texture *texture = SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface(renderer, surface);
    SDL_FreeSurface(surface);
    return texture;
}
```

If I comment out the line for SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface then the program works. I've checked SDL_GetError and TTF_GetError, both say there is no error. TTF initializes just fine. This code worked when I used to program on Linux but now I'm on Windows 10 and it doesn't.

This function is from the same class and works just fine and it also uses SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface.

```
SDL_Texture *Graphics::loadTexture(const char *path) {
    SDL_Surface *surface = IMG_Load(path);
    SDL_Texture *texture = SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface(renderer, surface);
    SDL_FreeSurface(surface);
    return texture;
}
```

Comment: Inspect values of `renderer`, `font`, `text` and `surface` right before this call. If none are null consider inspecting stacktrace of a crash and/or making minimal complete example.

Comment: I just went and added if statements to check if they were NULL. None of them are. How do I go about checking the stack trace?

Comment: With a debugger. I don't know what your toolchain is, if you use MSVC - use "run in debugger" and it should show stacktrace on break. If you use mingw - there is a `gdb` debugger with `backtrace` command. For better debugging you probably should build your program with debugging symbols and lower compiler optimisation (e.g. `-O0 -g3` for gcc or something similar for msvc cl).